# Push notifications no longer working in meteor cordova

Tags: android, ios, cordova, meteor, push-notification

I am using Meteor 1.4.1

Push notifications just suddenly stopped working on iOS and Android. Whenever I try to broadcast push notifications I get this error from the chrome console

```
GET http://app.myapp.com/sockjs/info?cb=kb6ea6scd6 net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

I also get this message on the server side

```
[WARNING:aw_network_delegate.cc(66)] http://app.cyclusbreak.com/sockjs/info?cb=q_f913x8wi#-102#1
```

This is when I send push notifications from production, in development I have the same issue but no errors.

I use the raix/Push library which is dependent on Cordova Push plugin. I am currently using these cordova plugins

```
cordova-plugin-device@1.1.3
cordova-plugin-dialogs@1.2.1
cordova-plugin-inappbrowser@1.3.0
cordova-plugin-vibration@2.1.1
de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification@0.8.4
phonegap-plugin-push@1.8.1
```

I am not sure what is wrong, any feedback or help would be greatly appreciated